# Jquery .ajax(): Unique AJAX query Identifier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have some ajax queries that create & manipulate (external) DOM elements during different stages of the AJAX query (beforeSend, success, failure, complete). Multiple queries can be fired while others are still processing, and I'm wondering how to identify the DOM elements for each query to trigger the events for the correct one.

So, does jQuery .ajax provide access to a unique query identifier that I can parse into an ID for each respective DOM element?

```javascript
$.ajax({
    UNIQUE_ID_NEEDED_HERE = ??? # Need to get unique identifier for this AJAX query
    url: '/my/query',
    data: my_data,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function (response) {
        $('#ajax_messages').append('<div class="loadingStatus" id="' + UNIQUE_ID_NEEDED_HERE + '">Re-ordering tasks</div>');
    },
    success: (message, text, response) {
        $(UNIQUE_ID_NEEDED_HERE).attr('class', 'successfulStatus');
        $(UNIQUE_ID_NEEDED_HERE).html('Tasks re-ordered');
    }
});
```

If not, any alternative ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
    var constructRequest = (function() {
        var startNumber = 0;
        return function() {
            var local = "request_id_"+(++startNumber);
            $.ajax({
              url: "someurl.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                /**
                 * Every time on success callback
                 * you will have unique local variable
                 * like this:
                 * request_id_1, request_id_2, request_id_3
                 * and so on.
                 ***/
                 alert(local);
              }
            });
        }
    })();

    $(document).ready(function() {
            constructRequest();
            constructRequest();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your purpose there's really no need to do this. All you need to do is create a standard "loading..." div template and clone it. store the clone in a variable and write it to the appropriate location in your document. When the AJAX success method fires it will do so inside the scope where it was created meaning you still have access to the same clone and can call any appropriate methods necessary on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
function doAjaxMagic(idOfEl){
 $.ajax
          url: '/my/query'
          data: my_data
          dataType: "json"
          beforeSend: (response) ->
            $('#ajax_messages').append('<div class="loadingStatus" id="' + idOfEl + '">Re-ordering tasks</div>')

          success: (message, text, response) ->
            $("#"+idOfEl).attr('class', 'successfulStatus')
            $("#"+idOfEl).html('Tasks re-ordered')


}
```

Is there a reason why that would not work?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately not quite. Certain commands can be fired from the same elements (eg the same sortable drag/drop lists being re-ordered), so I need to identify the query, not just the element from which it was fired. (Edit: With that said, I guess I could throw in a timestamp, but there is a theoretical risk of simultaneous ones.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a random number as the unique identifier greatly decreases the likelyhood of duplicating the identifier.